# getAttributeText not returning proper value for attributes of type "select"

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-collection

Why does my attribute return only "No" (even though some products have the attribute set to "Yes") when I try to access it from a collection, but does return "Yes" or "No" appropriately I load the product individually?

---

```
$attributes = array('my_attribute','another_attribute');

$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes);
$productsCollection->load();

foreach ($productsCollection as $_product) {
    $value = $_product->getAttributeText('my_attribute'); // only returns "No";
}
```

I can get it to return the proper value if I reload the product individually, but that's way too inefficient for my needs.

```
$attributes = array('my_attribute','another_attribute');

$productsCollection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes);
$productsCollection->load();

foreach ($productsCollection as $_product) {
    // Reload product individually
    $_product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')
                ->load($_product->getId());
    $value = $_product->getAttributeText('my_attribute');
    //return "Yes" and "No" appropriately;
}
```

How can I efficiently, grab "select" attribute values for thousands of products?

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$value = $prod->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($prod);
echo $value;
```

**When use Product flat setting enable:**

**Table:**

```
product  has been load from `catalog_product_flat_STOREID` table.
```

`load()`, product is load from  product master table `catalog_product_entity` with  join with `multiple models,modules`.

**Attributes:**

You can only get `few product attributes values Whose setting is enable for Use in Product listing.

load():get all attributevalues of a particular product with inventory prices,tax etc in full details.`

---

**Speedup:**

`load()` surely slow  because `multiple eav tables join,multiple module join like tax,inventory etcs`
When disable product Flat setting:

---

**Table:**

`product has`been load from catalog_product_entity  table and join multiple eav,products eav using `function like`addAttributeToSelect,addAttributeToSort,addAttributeToFilter()` etc.

`load()` same `AS whenever flat is enable`

**Attributes:**

`You can get` only those attribute value whose are  select via addAttributeToSelect.,addUrlRewriteToResult() etc.`

`load():` get `all attribute values  of a particular product with inventory prices, tax etc in full details`.

**Speedup:**

`T`otaly depend on attribute selection and join product t related models`.

load() s`urely slow  because multiple eav tables join, multiple module join like tax, inventory etc`.

As per my point view ,it totally depends on  attribute selection,filter etc  of product. If your attribute value is filled collection then you need to use collection.

Otherwise use Product model load. Because of collection is not enable giving all data

Comment: would this not have the issue of being inefficient, since it loads every product, as opposed to having it pre-grabbed at the collection level?

Comment: No,  'Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load()' is object of Magento product class Mage_Catalog_Product_Model and   $collection->getFirstItem() is object of Magento product collection class  Mage_Catalog_Product_Model_Resource_Product_Collection  or Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection   ok let me expain in another answer  it 's depends on magento flat setting

Comment: I tried running this code, and it returns only "No". It does not grab the correct values of the attribute